# Add custom Woocommerce product status usable with WC Vendors plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, vendor

With Woocommerce I am using a plugin called WC VENDORS. I would like to add custom product statuses that can be set by the seller and that should display as "For Sale" or "Not for Sale".

The vendor or the seller can either choose them and that should be reflected in the product details.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should better change your mind and use custom fields instead, as it will be much more easier in any way. You can [search on this threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+add+product+custom+field) for something that will allow to start something…

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of using the WC Vendors plugin, what you need is the ability to add a custom field for the Product post type. This custom field would hold the value "For Sale", "Not for Sale", or anything else you like.

I recommend using Advanced Custom Fields to create a new drop-down field associated with the Product post type. You provide the allowed values: "For Sale" etc. Once that is set up, vendors will be able to pick one of those values for each product. To display the value of the field in any template use `<?php the_field('is-for-sale'); ?>`, where "is-for-sale" is the slug of the new field.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are you referring to the plugin Advanced Custome fields? https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Yes, make sure you use the plugin of that name by Elliot Condon.